How can I create multiple markers in a single API call using the Google Maps API?

I am trying to create multiple markers in a single API call using the Google Maps API. Are there any possibilities for this, or alternative methods I could use? I have already tried the GeoJSON method to create multiple markers, but as of February 2024, this API has been deprecated.
Here is the approach I've tried so far:
const locations = [
  { lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 },
  { lat: 34.0522, lng: -118.2437 },
  { lat: 40.7128, lng: -74.0060 },
];

locations.forEach(location => {
  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
  });
});


While this works, it creates markers one at a time. Is there a way to batch create them more efficiently?
I've also read about google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement, but I'm not sure how to optimize it for multiple markers. Any suggestions or alternatives would be appreciated.

I'm trying to set strict bounds on a Google Map so that users cannot scroll or zoom out to see repeated maps. Here’s what I’ve implemented:
const bounds = {
  north: 85.15113,
  south: -85.15113,
  east: 180.0,
  west: -180.0,
};

map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setOptions({
  restriction: {
    latLngBounds: bounds,
    strictBounds: true,
  },
});


However, when I zoom out, I can still see three maps instead of one. What could be the issue? How can I ensure strict bounds are enforced?



for cluster display:
locations.forEach(location => {
new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
position: location,
map: map,
});
});

for bounds:
const bounds = {
north: 85.15113,
south: -85.15113,
east: 180.0,
west: -180.0,
};

const mapOptions = {
restriction: {
latLngBounds: bounds,
strictBounds: true, // This prevents panning and zooming outside the 
bounds
},
center: { lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 }, // Initial center position
zoom: 5, // Start with an appropriate zoom level
};

// Initialize the map
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), 
mapOptions);

// Set bounds and update the map to fit them
map.fitBounds(bounds);

PS: It will be more easier if done in react. you can use react-google-maps/api package for that.
A better explanation here

Hello Yashwini Thakur, Thank you for the response and the method you've used loop to create a marker right? But I've asked for creating multiple marker in a SINGLE API call. Also Still I can view three maps in my end.

And the values :
const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), { zoom: 5, center: { lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 },streetViewControl: false,zoomControl: false, mapTypeControl: true, mapTypeControlOptions: {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM,}, mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID",});const bounds = { north: 85.15113,south: -85.15113,east: 180.0,west: -180.0}; map.setOptions({restriction: {latLngBounds: bounds,strictBounds: true,},});map.fitBounds(bounds);

@ManishaG try checking out this thread at stack overflow

can you please confirm adding markers considers as a API call? and what components are consider for API call?

and using this method
locations.forEach(location => {
new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
position: location,
map: map,
});
});
if we have four locations it consumes 4 API call or a single API call? Can you please confirm this. My goal is to reduce the API for marker creation @yashwini-thakur
